# Return all possible combinations for each group

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have got a table looks like this one here shows the student ID and all classes this student took:

```
+-------------+
| ID | Class  |
+-------------+
| 01 |   A    |
| 01 |   B    |
| 01 |   C    |
| 02 |   A    |
| 02 |   C    |
| 02 |   D    |
| 03 |   A    |
| 03 |   B    |
+-------------+
```

And I would like to convert this table to the one below in order to see all possible combinations of classes for each student.

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | Class 1 | Class 2 |
+----+---------+---------+
| 01 | A       | B       |
| 01 | A       | C       |
| 01 | B       | C       |
| 02 | A       | C       |
| 02 | A       | D       |
| 02 | C       | D       |
| 03 | A       | B       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Does anyone know how to get this?

Comment: I have tried to use pivot table, but that would only return me 3 unique row for each ID, and Class 1, Class 2, Class 3 as three different columns.

Comment: Is the order of the classes important? I see you listed A, B as a possible combination, but not B, A.

Comment: The order is not important at all, that means A, B and B, A are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your dataset is small, something like this could be suitable:

```
select class1.id ,class1.class class1,class2.class class2 from 
t1 class1,
t1 class2
where
class1.id = class2.id and
class1.class < class2.class
order by id,class1,class2
```